# Very basic php/html form

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm very new to php/html, and I'm trying to teach myself the basics of creating and processing an html form.

I created a folder called Website. In it I created an html file index.html. I also created a file submit.php.

(this code is taken from: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

In index.html I have:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="submit.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

In submit.php I have:

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

When I open the html file in chrome and fill in the blanks and press submit, I get redirected to a page with the code in submit.php:

```
<html>
<body>
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I should be getting this output:

```
Welcome Hannah
Your email address is Hannah@example.com
```

What am I doing wrong that the output isn't working?
Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you don't have a webserver installed...

Comment: What output do you get? Or do you not get any output at all?

Comment: Side note, for when you get it working.  You should use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/function.htmlspecialchars.php) when outputting user input, for security reasons.  Check the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php).

Answer (score 2):

PHP is processed on a server, so you can't treat it like HTML, it needs to be placed on a server that has apache installed. You can install one on your computer, using something like the following:

- [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)
- [LAMP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lampas/)
- [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html)
- [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)

Comment: So how do I go about installing a server so that this works? This is likely a dumb question, but I really don't have any background at all! Thanks.

Comment: @user2994585 what OS are you running, Mac, Windows, Linux?

Comment: @user2994585 then just download the [mamp](http://www.mamp.info/) server and install it, be sure to put your files in the `htdocs`

Comment: Just did that -- downloaded MAMP and put the two files (index.html and submit.php) in the htdocs file. Then I went to chrome and opened index.html, filled out the form and hit submit. Same thing, not getting the right output...

Comment: Yes, I did, and I have two green lights for both servers. What do I type into the URL slot of Chrome/Safari/etc in order to properly open the file?

Comment: `localhost:8888/index.php` or `localhost/index.php` I don't know which one on a Mac, I never used it...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are doing this via files on your desktop and not via a web server.  Either on the Internet or via your local machine.  I took your example 100% as presented, placed it within my `htdocs` folder in MAMP (LAMP for the Macintosh) and it behaves 100% as expected.

The difference between loading files on your desktop versus a web server is a web server will process the PHP.  If you just do it as files, then the file gets loaded & doesn’t get parsed.